# Does IsConnected include Data Saver status?

Tags: android, android-datasaver

I use [`NetworkInfo.isConnected()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo#isConnected()) to determine if my app can make a web request:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected();
}
```

After the addition of [Data Saver](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0#data_saver) in Android N, is this method still reliable. In other words, if my app is restricted in the background on a metered network will `isConnected()` still return true?

Comment: I assume it will still return "connected" even when restricted. You can test it out by using adb commands to simulate device as unplugged and in saver mode

Comment: And the `adb` commands can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver